# How to get Row Values in a GRID field for a Submitted Form

Tags: google-docs-api

We're sending Form responses to a webhook via a Google Apps Script attached to the form. Works great except when we use a GRID field type in the Form (eg see below)

[image: Grid Field]

we can only seem to get the column value for each row but not the row value.

So, in the grid field example we get an array as follows
(element 1) = OPPORTUNITY: OT Not Considered;
(element 2) = OPPORTUNITY: OT Considered

Is there a way we can also get the Row values?

Option 1 a second parallel array
(element 1) = OT 1;
(element 2) = OT 2

or Option 2
(element 1) = OT 1&&OPPORTUNITY: OT Not Considered;
(element 2) = OT 2&&OPPORTUNITY: OT Considered

Here's the GAS we're currently using to get the Form Submission

```html
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 var data = {
      "id": e.source.getId(),
   "OTC_user" : Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),
      "title": e.source.getTitle() ? e.source.getTitle() : "Untitled Form",
      "is_private": e.source.requiresLogin(),
      "is_published": e.source.isAcceptingResponses(),
      "id": e.response.getId(),
      "timestamp": e.response.getTimestamp(),
      "fields": e.response.getItemResponses().map(function(y) {
    return {
        h: y.getItem().getTitle(),
        k: y.getResponse()
    }
      }, this).reduce(function(r, y) {
    r[y.h] = y.k;
    return r
      }, {})
 };

 var options = {
  method: "post",
  payload: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 };

 UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://<WEBHOOK URL REMOVED", options);
};
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way to get the Row values. When you use the [`getItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response.html#getItem()), which returns an [interface item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item.html), you can specify that you want a [GridItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item.html) using the method [`asGridItem()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item.html#asGridItem()), in that way you will be able to get the Row values simply by calling the method [`getRows()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/grid-item.html#getRows()). This is a small example code to give you a better idea about the privious explanation I wrote:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var itemVals = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getItem().asGridItem();
  var rowVals = itemVals.getRows();
  var colVals = itemVals.getColumns();
  rowVals.forEach(function(e){Logger.log(e)});
  colVals.forEach(function(e){Logger.log(e)});
}
```